# POSTing JSON with Play 1.2.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now and I just can't seem to make it work properly. I have this POST service that accepts JSON content:

```
public static void addLifestyleToRecipes(String categoryMappingList) {
    Logger.info("In RecipeServices--> addLifestyleToRecipes");
    Logger.info("JSON received: %s", categoryMappingList);      
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<CategoryMapping>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<CategoryMapping> categoryMapping = new Gson().fromJson(categoryMappingList, type);

    for (CategoryMapping cat : categoryMapping) {
            //the rest is irrelevant to the problem

}
```

When I test my method with a functionnal test, everything works fine :

```
List<CategoryMapping> list = new ArrayList<CategoryMapping>();
list.add(new CategoryMapping(MULTI_LANG_ID, recipes));
list.add(new CategoryMapping(MULTI_LANG_ID, recipes));

String body = new Gson().toJson(list);

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("categoryMappingList", body);

StringBuffer url = TestHelper.generateBaseUrl(apiKey, apiVersion);
url.append("/recipes/add/categories");

Response response = POST(url, params);
```

The problem comes when I try to actually call the service, my parameter "categoryMappingList" is always null. I also tried using Chrome's "Advanced Rest Client" to simulate a POST request but I always get the same result.

I also noticed that if I specified my Content-Type to be anything but "application/json; charset=utf-8", I get a 403 error.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add your client code that calls the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your functional test you are adding the json as a parameter

```
/recipes/add/categories?categoryMappingList=json
```

If your client call is instead posting it in the body this will not be picked up in the *categoryMappingList* argument. To parse json from POST body

```
categoryMappingList = request.getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but have you looked in the request().body to see if your JSON is there?